# Playing MIDI files on PhoneGap on Android

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, midi

How can I play MIDI files on PhoneGap?

The only MIDI PhoneGap plugin I have seen is for IOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it seems, this Plugin support android MidiPlayer although its not stated in its README file. Please check it out:
https://github.com/NormannEiland/MidiFilePlayer

Edit: Now it seems to be in the README :)

Comment: Thanks the pligin was recently updated for android. cheked it some weeks ago.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to make an android application and you need to program a midi file, you could use the android sdk 23.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/midi/package-summary.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [cordova-open](https://github.com/disusered/cordova-open.git) plugin, it allows you to open audio, video, images and more with applications installed on the user's device.